# Differences between 访问，面试 and 采访

Tags: word-choice, mandarin

All 3 words seem to mean to interview, interview but what are the differences between them?

Comment: Notice words usually  don't have one-to-one mapping between human languages.

Answer (score 3):

面试, literally 'in-person test', refers to interview or admission test for a job or school application.

采访, literally 'pick and reach out', refers to journalist interviewing a random or specific person on the scene.

访问, literally 'reach out and inquire', refers to someone paying some specific person or place a visit with in-depth conversations, e.g. a journalist interviewing a domain expert, or a president visiting another country.

Comment: "reach out"? where does this translation comes from? Source? Thanks.

Comment: 面试 = "face test/trial"

Answer (score 2):

for differences users suggest consulting online dictionaries, esp. bkrs, iciba (anyhow which resource would only supply "interview" for all３?)bkrs: all 3 can be nouns,as verbs:

**访问**： (1) [visit; call on]∶拜访, 有目的地探望天刚黑时去访问了几位朋友
(2) [go sightseeing; visit]∶观光; 游历 想在一个月后访问英国 CL:次 总统正在访问欧洲 "interview": 记者访问了这位战斗英雄。 A reporter interviewed the combat hero freq. rank  #726  同义/synonyms: 拜访, 拜会, 造访, 走访

**面试** to be interviewed (as a candidate)当面考试 mainly used as noun ((就某问题)交谈, 面谈; 座谈) #5679

**采访**[cover; gather material report] 采集素材, 调查访问
调查刑事案时采访证人to interview to gather news
to hunt for and collect to cover 1) 搜集寻访；探问寻访。2) 见“采访使”hist. informant, responsible for gathering information about conduct of other officials,Tang Dyn. 唐朝  #1161